# What is the time complexity for AngularJS's dirty checking algorithm?

Tags: angularjs, performance, algorithm, data-binding, time-complexity

While recently developing an AngularJS app I came across performance issues related to watches, digging down further makes me wonder what is the time complexity for the dirty checking algorithm using two-way data binding? From the looks of it, after every event there's a digest cycle, which inturn calls a watch cycle, so this must be O(n^2)... is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dirty checking happens in the `$diggest` cycle, so we need to study the complexity of the `$diggest` cycle.

The `$diggest` cycle is the stage in which Angular ensures the changes of the model have settled,
so that it can render the view with the updated changes. In order to do that,
Angular starts a loop in which each iteration evaluates all the template expressions
of the view, as well as the `$watcher` functions of the `$scope`.
If in the current iteration the result is the same as the previous one,
then Angular will exit the loop. Otherwise, it will try again.
If after 10 attempts things haven't settled, Angular will exit
with an error: The ["*Infite $diggest Loop Error*" (`infdig`)](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig).

Therefore the complexity of the dirty checking will deppend on the complexity of the functions that you have in the `$watcher`s and in the expressions of your view (like your `$filter`s).

So the `$diggest` cycle alone has a complexity of `O(n)` where `n` is the number o `$watcher`s and template expressions that need to be iterated. But then you will have to consider the complexity of those functions. Also, notice that the `$diggest` cycle will always visit all those functions at least twice (in order to make sure that the changes have settled), so if you want to be more precise you could say that it has a complexity of at least `O(n*2)` and a maximum complexity of `O(n*10)`, but since 2 is a constant value which its max number is 10 the complexity should still be considered `O(n)`.